# NSTableView early detection of edit session

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I've a NSTableView (view-based) whose delegate (my windowcontroller, in this case) needs to be notified as early as possibile of Text editing session starts.
I've tried with the Text Delegate method

`- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor;`

but this not working in my case.
The event gets triggered (and the delegate invoked) if and only if i hit some key in the keyboard.
If, by any chance, i click outside the control without having typed anything, the edit session silently stops without notifying anybody.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if there's a better method, but a hack where you subclass the nstextfield and override the method `mouseDown:` and then notifying the delegate should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@theAmateurProgrammer
Thank you for your suggestion. Well, what you suggest would do only in case of mouse events. Instead, i need to detect the start edit session event *always*, also in case of, for example, programmatically triggered editing.
However i've found the solution. I subclass the table view and then i override the validateProposedFirstResponder method.
The responder, actually, is the TextField which is about to start editing.